# css - Can't select text inside div

Tags: html, css

I will soon be crazy about that, trying to findout what causes it for hours and still not able to get it. I have a fixed div and another relative div inside. However, even I gave z-index of 999999, I still can't select the text. Where I am doing wrong ?

```
<div style="top:500px;position:fixed;width:300px;
height:100px;background-color:#cad4de;
padding:22px;z-index:1;height:476px;width:527px;">

<div style="position:relative;z-index:9999999">Text to select</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I just tried and it works just fine [Working Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ru6qxq01/)

Comment: Why do you define the width twice on the parent?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<div style="top: 500px; position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: #cad4de; padding: 22px; z-index:1; height: 476px; width: 527px;">
<div style="position: relative; width: 500px; z-index:9999999;">Text to select</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have given top as 500px.
Apart from this, dont write inline styles.
Check the following code snippet

```css
.div2{
  position:relative;
    z-index:9999999;
}
.div1{
  position:fixed;
  width:300px;
height:100px;
  background-color:#cad4de;
padding:22px;
  z-index:1;height:476px;width:527px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">

<div class="div2">Text to select</div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps